# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState On Activity Backpress (Not using any fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

In my application I am getting  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState. after onBackPress() of Activity.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(MyApplication:1533)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(MyApplication:603)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(MyApplication:179)
       at com.app.mobile.views.NewsActivity.onBackPressed(MyApplication:301)
       at com.app.mobile.views.NewsActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MyApplication:293)
       at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2625)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(MyApplication:406)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(MyApplication:195)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(MyApplication:103)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(MyApplication:103)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper$1.onClick(MyApplication:183)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4446)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18437)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5447)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

In my activity I am not using any fragment. I searched for solution, but found only for fragments.

In my code.

```
@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

and

```
 @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (screen_Name != 0 && screen_Name == Constants.TAG_WIDGET_SCREEN) {
      int tagID = getIntent().getIntExtra(Constants.TAG_ID, -1);
      int tagcount = getIntent().getIntExtra(Constants.TAG_COUNT, 0);
      if (tagcount > 0) {
        mDBAdapter.updateTagCountToZero(tagID);
      }
      PreferenceUtils.getInstance(NewsActivity.this).remove(Constants.NEWS + type);
      PreferenceUtils.getInstance(NewsActivity.this).remove(Constants.CARD_PREF + cardPref);

    }
  }
```

in onSavedInstance

```
@Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    if (feedList != null && feedList.size() > 0) {
      outState.putSerializable(FEED_DATA, feedList);
    }
    stopProgressBar(); // stopping progress dialog
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  }
```

Please help how to handle this situation.

Comment: I am just guessing randomly, but did you try putting ```super.onBackPressed();``` at the end of your method? maybe that triggeres already something like onSaveInstanceState

Comment: but this is not reproduced. This came in live apk. So i don't know the exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this problem, you can check if your activity is finishing:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!isFinishing()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (screen_Name != 0 && screen_Name == Constants.TAG_WIDGET_SCREEN) {
            int tagID = getIntent().getIntExtra(Constants.TAG_ID, -1);
            int tagcount = getIntent().getIntExtra(Constants.TAG_COUNT, 0);
            if (tagcount > 0) {
                mDBAdapter.updateTagCountToZero(tagID);
            }
            PreferenceUtils.getInstance(NewsActivity.this).remove(Constants.NEWS + type);
            PreferenceUtils.getInstance(NewsActivity.this).remove(Constants.CARD_PREF + cardPref);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Super.onBackPressed()
```

will invoke finish on your activity. If you want finish the activity, first perform what is required for you and then call this at the end.

Comment: Hi, please see in logs, exception is being occur at FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(MyApplication:1533).

Comment: I am doing just SharedPreference related task after super.backPressed(). If you see in the flow onOptionsItemSelected() -> onBackPressed -> ...checkStateLoss() and Exception. So I think exception occur before Preference task.

Comment: Can u move the super.onBackpressed() method call to the end of onBackPressed() method? As i mentioned, super.onBackPressed() will trigger finish on activity.

Comment: Ok I will move, But this issue is not reproduced. This came in live apk. So I don't know exact reason. I will call super.onBackPressed() at the end. I hope it will work. I just want to know reason

Comment: This error is straight forward and nothing specific to fragments. This says that we can perform any operations that changes the activity's current state as onSavedInstance on activity is already called which means that this activity already lost user focus.

Comment: can isFinishing() help in this case.

Comment: isFinishing() is a patch work in this case, it will just save you from the crash, but you many not be able to perform the task which u wanted when onBackPressed(). So better to find the root cause of the issue. Note: there is a typo in my previous comment. it should be "Can not perform"